# Material UI Autocomplete Render Option

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a material-ui autocomplete showing **two fields divided by  "|" and right aligned**. I tried different methods and checked the documentations but couldn't find any solution.Thanks for you help.

Comment: You can format your option data to `xxx|xxx`, as for right aligned, use the custom style setting method in Material-UI refer to `Autocomplete` css document [here](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#css)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I couldn't make it work. Could you please provide me with an example code?

Comment: you could use `getLabelOption`...check the docs

Answer (score 0):

```
renderOption={(option: any, state) => {(
    <ListboxItem selected={state.selected}>
      <span>{option.field1} | {option.field2}</span>
    </ListboxItem>
)}
```

Use **renderOption** to build a custom option, make sure **ListboxItem** has corresponding styles. To make a custom input use **renderInput**.